# Selenium Web driver is not able to find the div class in Google Chrome webstore

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to crawl some data from [Google Chrome Website](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/recommended_extensions?hl=en). But I am facing a problem whenever trying to use selenium webdriver. When I use following code I get an error stating that this element doesn't exist in the site.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-d-l-L")
```

Snapshot of the website:
[image]

And also, how to get data from a pop up window (this window comes up when I press a button). Following screen can be found on the next page. I want to store the data that is showing in the pop up message.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Google has special permissions on the Chrome Webstore, as of now you can't use Selenium to automate any page on the Chrome Webstore website.

Comment: so what will be the alternative?